# Freeform Multiselect populated by relationship field

Tags: solspace-freeform, relationships, grid, multiselect, options

I am using the latest version of Freeform and trying to populate a multi-select with a relationship field of entries. Here is the code, at the moment it is only outputting the first result and not looping properly. Has anyone tried this before and can therefore advise?

```
{related_documents_for_request}
            <select id="{selected_documents:title}" name="{selected_documents:title}" multiple="multiple"> 
                  {options}
                      <option value="{related_documents_for_request:selected_documents:title}"{selected}>{related_documents_for_request:selected_documents:title}</option>
                  {/options}
             </select>
{/related_documents_for_request}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a Freeform custom field called `my_multi_select_field`. Let's also assume the fieldtype is a *textarea*, since it can contain multiple values, which in turn are saved as newline-separated data if the data comes in as an *array* (as would happen with a multi-select field).

Let's assume you're using the native EE relationship field, and that it's called `related_documents_for_request`. In that case, try this code:

```
<select name="my_multi_select_field" multiple="multiple"> 
   {related_documents_for_request}
   <option value="{related_documents_for_request:title}">{related_documents_for_request:title}</option>
   {/related_documents_for_request}
</select>
```

If your relationship field comes from a native EE Grid field which in turn contains a native EE Relationship column, then the above code would have to be tweaked, but the main point is that the opening and closing `<select>` element tags should be **outside** of the looping part of the code, and that the `<select>` element's `name=""` should be the name of your Freeform custom field.